# How websphere server creates and manages JMS resources internally

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

When we set up a queue connection factory, a topic connection factory, a queue, a topic in websphere application server throguh the console, what exactly happens?

The server stores the configuration details in an xml and at server startup, it creates the connection factory(ies), topic(s),queue(s) and puts them in a pool?

I ask because the actual queue(s) and topics(s) itself do not reside on the App server, they reside on a separate (remote) websphere MQ server. So why do we need to 'create' the queues in Websphere App server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is metadata for connecting to the remote objects.  When the server starts (or an app restarts, or configuration is refreshed), the server reads the .xml, then binds Reference objects into JNDI.  The actual connection factories aren't created/pooled until the Reference is first looked up.

I don't have enough experience with JMS to answer your second question, but presumably the metadata is required for the queue in order to access it remotely.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you find the answer to the second question, please do share :)